# ReactJS: Function run multiple times without being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there any reason a function in a react component would run multiple times although it is being invoked only once?

I have this test function that auto-invokes itself as in:

```
  let xfunction = (() =>
   {
     console.log('test');
   }
  )();
```

This is what I get in the console:

[image]

App.js Source Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getAllPokemons } from './services/pokemon'
import './App.css';
function App() {


  const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const initialUrl = 'payload.json'


  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let response = await getAllPokemons(initialUrl);
      console.log(response);
      await loadingPokemon(response.pokemon);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchData();

  }, [])

  const loadingPokemon = async (data) => {
    let _pokemon = await Promise.all(data.map(async pokemon => {
      return pokemon;
    })
    );
    setPokemonData(_pokemon);
  }




  // Start - Filter by Pokemon Type
  let pokemonTypes = (() =>
   {
    console.log('test');
   }

  )();



// End - Filter by Pokemon Type

  return (

    <div></div>

  );


}

export default App;
```

The function is not being called or references anywhere else!

Thanks!

Comment: React component re renders so the function is called each time.

Comment: Is that a normal behavior for react?

Comment: The component is function or class component please show complete code.

Comment: Just did! Please check it out.

Comment: Yes that's normal behavior. If you want it not to rerun stick it in a useEffect hook like your fetch.

Comment: If you are writing this self calling function inside the pure component then it will call for each render this is the expected behavior. Can you please give some more detail?

Comment: @Jared Smith so you are saying I should not sweat over it? Just ignore!

Comment: @JaredSmith that works perfect, which leads me to another question. Should I call all my function inside the useEffect hook?

Comment: Only if you don't want them to run on every rerender. Otherwise you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Solution as proposed by @Jared Smith:

If you do not want your functions rerendered and you are using react hooks, please include them in the useEffect hook as in:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let response = await getAllPokemons(initialUrl);
      await loadingPokemon(response.pokemon);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchData();
    includeFunctionHere();

  }, [])
```